# Dada un clave JSON mostrar un registro - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito obtener el registro que se encuentra dentro de una tabla en la cual hay una columna tipo *JSON* en el que una de sus claves coincide con una dada.

```
SELECT json_object_keys("Localizacion") LIKE 'prop1' 
FROM ejemplo "EstanciaHospitalaria"
```

Devuelve si en cada registro la clave coincide con alguna o no, si coincide devuelve `t` y si no coincide devuelve `f`.

Lo que quiero mostrar realmente es toda la información que se encuentre en el registro de la tabla, en el código de arriba devuelve `t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una expresión `EXISTS` de esta manera:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ejemplo "EstanciaHospitalaria"
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
    FROM json_object_keys("Localizacion") jkey
   WHERE jkey LIKE 'prop1'
)
```

.. y siendo que no estás comparando nada especial con el operador `LIKE`, en este caso puedes simplemente usar el operador `=` y obtener los mismos resultados:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ejemplo "EstanciaHospitalaria"
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
    FROM json_object_keys("Localizacion") jkey
   WHERE jkey = 'prop1'
)
```

[**Demostración en vivo**](http://rextester.com/ZTXNY51931).

Comment: Muchas gracias, muestra exactamente lo que queria obtener :)

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo quieres retornar el valor del json cada vez que se cumpla que la clave es igual a cierto valor?. Si es así, esta sería una posible solución:

```
select js, js_key, case when js_key = 'Localizacion' then js->>'Localizacion' end as Lozalizacion
from (select '{"Id": "1","Localizacion": "Chile"}'::json js, json_object_keys('{"Id": "1","Localizacion": "Chile"}'::json) js_key) a;
```